# how to intercept all requests in spring REST controllers?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a bunch of controllers like:

```
@RestController
public class AreaController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/area", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Area> get(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Serializable id) { ... }
}
```

and I need to intercept all the requests that reach them,

I created an interceptor like this example:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

but it never enters :(

because I'm using only annotations, i don't have a XML to define the interceptor,
what I've found its to set it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.app")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ControllerInterceptor getControllerInterceptor() {
        ControllerInterceptor c = new ControllerInterceptor();
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getControllerInterceptor());
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }

}
```

what am i doing wrong or am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so apparently i was doing something wrong but can't say what,

defining the interceptor like:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.test.ControllerInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

I'm pretty sure that you can also define it in pure java, but this is working,

answer found in: 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/

Answer (score 3):

your `Interceptor` class `ControllerInterceptor` isn't an application context managed bean. Make sure you put `@Component` annotation on ControllerInterceptor  and add it's package to `@ComponentScan`. So, let's say your `ControllerInterceptor` resides in package com.xyz.interceptors like:

```
package com.xyz.interceptors;  //this is your package

@Component //put this annotation here
public class ControllerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
 // code here
}
```

and your AppConfig becomes:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test.app", "com.xyz.interceptors" })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible you are missing mapping

```
registry.addInterceptor(getControllerInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
```

And as I know you don't have to use

```
super.addInterceptors(registry);
```

Comment: Is this spring boot or just plain Spring MVC app? And if you can share code of your interceptor.

Comment: at the beginning it was springBoot, but we come across some problems and now is plain Spring

Comment: If this is not spring boot so are you sure your AppConfig has been registered in your AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext at startup?

Comment: yes it is loaded: <bean id="appConfig" class="com.test.AppConfig"></bean>