# Intercept calls to RestController in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've looked at similar problems:

[how to intercept all requests in spring REST controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232597/how-to-intercept-all-requests-in-spring-rest-controllers)

[spring boot adding http request interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082981/spring-boot-adding-http-request-interceptors)

And still can't figure out the solution.
I have a Spring Boot app that runs a bunch of Rest Controllers and want to intercept calls and perform some business logic before the request is passed to the controllers. I have this:

My Application class for Sprint Boot:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.application;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.controllers")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My Configuration class in same package a Application:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.application;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.interceptors.MyInterceptor;

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Bean
    public MyInterceptor getInterceptor() {
        return new MyInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors (InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("\n\nAdding interceptors\n\n");
        registry.addInterceptor(getInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

And finally the interceptor class:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.interceptors;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.print("\\n\\nIn MyInterceptor.preHandle\\n\\n");
        String token = request.getParameter("token");

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(token)) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid User Id or Password. Please try again.");
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            Exception exception) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("\n\nIn MyInterceptor.afterCompletion\\n\\n");
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("\\n\\nIn MyInterceptor.postHandle\\n\\n");
    }
}
```

The Configuration class never seems to get called to register the interceptors nor does MyInterceptor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.controllers")` only annotated components from `com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.controllers` package and it's sub packages will be discovered.

You `MyConfiguration` class is in `com.amazonaws.lambda.keefinty.application` package which is not part of the declared component scan package.

One way to resolve this is to remove `scanBasePackages` argument from your `@SpringBootApplication` declaration. This will allow `MyConfiguration` to be component scanned as by default the package in which `@SpringBootApplication` is declared is component scanned.

Comment: I've added the package name in the scan and that worked. I thought that Spring Boot would automatically look in the same package as the Application. Thanks.

Comment: Of note is that it is actually a good idea to indicate the packages to be scanned so as to speed up start up of the application. For example, various packages with simple non-Spring managed POJOs do not need to be scanned.