# Spring Interceptor and AuthenticationFilter Order of Execution

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a LoginHandler and an Interceptor. I want the Interceptor to execute before the `AuthenticationFilter`. Is there a way to specify the order of execution?

UPDATED:
The title mentioned  `LoginHandler`. I changed it to `AuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: execution orders in spring are usually specified using the `org.springframework.core.Ordered` interface, not sure if this works in your case but you could give it a spin.

Comment: If you want to execute something during the life-cycle of the component, then refer docs section: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle
If you want to intercept the method then you can use the spring AOP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to intercept all requests in spring REST controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232597/how-to-intercept-all-requests-in-spring-rest-controllers)

Comment: @SudhirDhumal I'm not asking about how to implement `Interceptors` because I already have an interceptor. What I'm asking is how the interceptor can be prioritized over the `AuthenticationFilter`

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you configured the AuthenticationFilter and Interceptor

Comment: An interceptor is always executed after a filter. The Filter is a part of the servlet spec the interceptor executes as part of the request handling of the `DispatcherServlet`. Filters always execute before servlets, hence an interceptor is always called after the filter. No annotations, ordering can change that.

Comment: Why do you  need the interceptor to execute before the filters? That simply isn't possible, what is so important in the interceptor that you need to do it before the filters (looks like you should actually be hooking into Spring Security, as you now apparently work around it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `HandlerInterceptor` from Spring will never execute before a filter.

The `javax.servlet.Filter` is part of the Java Servlet API and requests always first pass through `Filter` instances, before reaching a `Servlet`.

`HandlerInterceptor` instances are executed as part of the request handling inside the `DispatcherServlet` (which implements `javax.servlet.Servlet`). As mentioned the flow is `Filter` -> `Servlet` the result is that a `HandlerInterceptor` will always execute after a `Filter`.

So is what you want possible, no it isn't. No matter how much ordering you add to the `HandlerInterceptor`.

Comment: Alright, then i'll just use a filter instead of an interceptor